# Malloc , Realloc , Memset : Struct pointers , arrays of char, int

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, realloc

```
#ifndef vECTOR_h
#define vECTOR_h

#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* My iterator is an int but thanks to this typedef I could change it easily */
typedef int iterator;
#define iterator_begin 0
#define iterator_end -1

//typedef is for vector_type and in the meanwhile struct vector_struct is defined 
typedef struct vector_struct {
    size_t e_sz; //size of a single element in e_array in bytes, size_t is always unigned and machine/compiler bounded usually undsinged long
    char e_type; //type of a single element in e_array used rarely since we go with void pointers

     #define V_INT 1
     #define V_DOUBLE 2
     #define V_CHAR 3
     #define V_FLOAT 4

    unsigned no_e;  //number of elements in e_array with a value , unsigned    alone means unsigned int
    unsigned cur_cap; //max capacity of e_array at that moment
    void* e_array;  //real data
}* vector_type;

#define vector_size(v) ((v)->no_e)
#define vector_capacity(v) ((v)->cur_cap)
#define vector_int_at(v,i) (*((int*)v_at(v,i)))
#define vector_double_at(v,i) (*((double*)v_at(v,i)))
#define vector_char_at(v,i) (*((char*)v_at(v,i)))
#define vector_string(v) ((char*)v_at(v,0))
#define vector_float_at(v,i) (*((float*)v_at(v,i)))
//not necessary defines

 //Allocate space for a vector struct and initialize some elements 
vector_type v_create_empty(char type){ 
    vector_type my_v = (vector_type)check_a(malloc(sizeof(struct vector_struct)));

//since it's used only here we could drop type and receive size direclty where in vector.h we #define V_INT_S sizeof(int)
//on the other hand a better typed implementation would do a large use of e_type, less void pointer and more typed casts
    my_v->e_sz = (type == V_INT ? sizeof(int) : type == V_DOUBLE ? sizeof(double) : type == V_FLOAT ? sizeof(float) : 1); //1 for default is char then sizeof(char)

    my_v->e_type = type;
    my_v->no_e = my_v->cur_cap = 0;
    my_v->e_array = NULL;
    return my_v;
}

void* v_at(vector_type v, iterator i){
    if ( v == NULL )
        fail("v_at() Error: no such vector");
    if ( i == iterator_end )
        i = v->no_e -1;
    if ( i < 0 || i >= v->no_e )
        fail("v_at() Error: no such element in this vector");

    return (void*)((char*)v->e_array + (i * v->e_sz)) ;  //i sum char to char  
//in order to get the specified position of variable type casting to void*  for the return value
//
//typed alternative solution
//
//    switch(v->type)
//    {
//    case V_INT:
//         return ((void*)((int*)v->e_array) + i) ;
//          break;
//    case V_DOUBLE:
//         return ((void*)((double*)v->e_array) + i) ;
//          break;
//    case V_FLOAT:
//        return ((void*)((float*)v->e_array) + i) ;
//          break;
//    default:
//         return ((void*)((char*)v->e_array) + i) ;
//          break;
//    }
}

//Function to push some elements back to the first v->e_array void pointer and so on
void v_push_back(vector_type v, void* new_val){
    if ( v->no_e >= v->cur_cap ) {
        /*** reallocate a larger array ***/
        v->cur_cap += (v->cur_cap)? v->cur_cap : 2; 
        //add 2 elements if v->cur_cap is 0

        //if that's first call malloc will be used
        void *ptr = realloc(v->e_array,v->cur_cap * v->e_sz);
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            ptr = check_a(malloc(v->cur_cap * v->e_sz));
            memcpy(ptr, v->e_array ,v->no_e * v->e_sz);
            free(v->e_array);
            v->e_array = ptr;
        }
    v->e_array = check_a(realloc(v->e_array,v->cur_cap * v->e_sz));  
    //v->cur_cap * v->e_sz is never 0
    }
   /*** copy new_val in the array at index v->no_e ***/
     v->e_array = check_a(memcpy((void*)((char*)v->e_array + (v->no_e * v->e_sz)) , new_val, v->e_sz));    

    (v->no_e)++;
}

// v_push_back FUNCTION CALLED LIKE THIS from main in another c file: 
// the purpose is to link all characters in an array of characters
c1 = 'c'; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1);
c1 = 'i'; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1);
c1 = 'a'; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1);
c1 = 'o'; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1);
c1 = 0; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1);

printf("Vector vc1 now contains %d characters (capacity=%d): %s\n",
       vector_size(vc1)/**((v)->no_e)**/,vector_capacity(vc1)/** ((v)->cur_cap)**/,vector_string(vc1))/** ((char*)v_at(v,0))**/; // ==>ERROR DOESN 'T PRINT THE %s of (char*)v_at(v,0)
```

I can't print the value of the string created by pushing back the elements of the array list, no segmentation fault during debugging, you'll read sometimes about function check_a(pointer*) it only contains a control for a NULL pointer, called every time after a malloc, realloc... command

Lot of code missing but here is the part that is faulty
This is a program that should implement an array of float, int etc; so casting to void* is necessary to maintain versatility, sometimes casting to char* to move byte-per-byte.

Comment: don't post your entire program, narrow down the part with a problem. this question is very unclear and to much to read through.

Comment: i swear that if you read it will not seem complicated

Comment: i tryed to semplify much possible the range where i get the error you don t need any more to help me I think

Comment: can t get why so much down vote I tried to be as clear as possible

Comment: no error only inability to print the entire array after pushing back

Comment: ahh maybe improve your grammar a bit at the end, i am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: printf("Vector vc1 now contains %d characters (capacity=%d): %s\n",
       vector_size(vc1)/**((v)->no_e)**/,vector_capacity(vc1)/** ((v)->cur_cap)**/,vector_string(vc1))/** ((char*)v_at(v,0))**

Comment: can t print last variable gived by (char*)v_at(v,0)

Comment: edit that in your question dude not comments

Comment: Also if you want people to read your code, fix the indention.

Comment: Done, nobody has some idea about ?

Comment: Still can t get why -7 downvotes

Comment: You need to *edit* your question to make it easier to understand what you're asking  (**not** by adding comments). It is very hard for someone to help you if they don't understand what you need help with. At the moment it is very unclear what it is you are asking, even when reading the additional comments.

Comment: if you tell me the problem i will fix it

Comment: it s a pity because this exercise should be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in v_push_back implementation :

```
v->e_array = check_a(memcpy((void*)((char*)v->e_array + (v->no_e * v->e_sz)) ,new_val, v->e_sz)); //pointer has not to be saved

 check_a(memcpy((void*)((char*)v->e_array + (v->no_e * v->e_sz)) ,new_val, v->e_sz));
```

Because memcpy returns a pointer , in this case, to the last element of the array so we would have lost access to all previous memory